# Which library should I use on OSX for arbitrary precision arithmetic?

Tags: ios, macos, llvm, gmp, arbitrary-precision

I tried already GMP, MPFR. But I can't accomplish a simple division like below. BTW I have LLVM compiler in Xcode. I try to compile, run it to IOS Simulator.

> mpf_t a;
>
> mpf_init2 (a, 256);
>
> mpf_set_d(a, 0.7);
>
> mpf_t b; mpf_init2 (b, 256);
>
> mpf_set_d(b, 1.0);
>
> mpf_t l; mpf_init2 (l, 256);
>
> gmp_printf ("%.*Ff \n", 5, a);    --- 0.70000
>
> gmp_printf ("%.*Ff \n", 5, b);    --- 1.00000
>
> mpf_div(l, a, b);
>
> gmp_printf ("%.*Ff", 5, l);       --- 0.52502

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/)? [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) also provides a big number library...