# Using NSDecimalNumber for Fibonacci series with Binet's formula

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fibonacci, nsdecimalnumber

I've spent considerable time today trying to calculate the Fibonacci nth term when n is a very large number. I decided to use Objective-C which in hindsight may not have been the best decision, considering how long it has taken. I researched and decided to use Binet's formula which seems to work for other people using other programming languages.

```
double phi = (sqrt(5) + 1) / 2.0;
long long j = (long long) round(pow(phi, number) / sqrt(5));
```

Is the gist of a fibonacci(number) function in C. I tried converting this to Objective-C using NSDecimalNumber, my method looks like this:

```
NSDecimalNumber* squareRootOfFive = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqrt(5)] stringValue]];
NSDecimalNumber* phi = [[squareRootOfFive decimalNumberByAdding:[NSDecimalNumber one]] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2"]];

return [[[phi decimalNumberByRaisingToPower: number] decimalNumberByDividingBy:squareRootOfFive] decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior: [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:  NSRoundPlain scale:2 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:YES raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:NO ]];
```

Wonderfully readable I know. This code works for the first X Fibonacci number with X being greater than 700 but less than 800. I eventually get this error/output:

2013-02-01 17:27:19.977 Euler25[14907:303] Fibonacci number 792 has 166 digits

2013-02-01 17:27:19.989 Euler25[14907:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'

*** First throw call stack:

```
0   CoreFoundation   0x00007fff8c3b10a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198

1   libobjc.A.dylib  0x00007fff880443f0 objc_exception_throw + 43

2   CoreFoundation   0x00007fff8c3b0e7c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204

3   Foundation       0x00007fff8c88bc3d -[NSDecimalNumberHandler exceptionDuringOperation:error:leftOperand:rightOperand:] + 193

4   Foundation       0x00007fff8c88ad46 _checkErrorAndRound + 60

5   Foundation       0x00007fff8c88b1e2 -[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:withBehavior:] + 156

6   Euler25          0x0000000100001bb2 +[Euler25 fibonacci:] + 402

7   Euler25          0x0000000100001978 main + 184

8   libdyld.dylib    0x00007fff8a5147e1 start + 0

9   ???              0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Which I can't get to format pretty. I was using this code to solve Project euler [Problem 25](  [1]: http://projecteuler.net/
  [2]: https://projecteuler.net/problem=25),  how does one work with large number in Objective-C if not with NSDecimalNumber, I'm not sure  how to proceed further with this problem, perhaps there is some math trick I should be using?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have run into the maximum value that a `NSDecimalNumber` can hold.  There is a function which can tell you exactly what it is.  Try:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDecimalNumber maximumDecimalNumber]);
```

It will give you:

> 3402823669209384634633746074317682114550000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Which happens to be 166 digits.

Objective-C/C does not support numbers larger than that, so you will need to use an Arbitrary Precision Math library.  Here is another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1226949/937822) which discusses some options.

**EDIT:**
Also, as Metabble mentions below, the maximum number of digits in the mantissa is 38 digits.  This means that any calculation which results in a value larger than 38 digits will be truncated and stored with a mantissa keeping track of the number of remaining digits.  When you access the results, every digit after the 38th one will be 0, which results in an incorrect value.

Comment: +1. I'd just like to add that the documentation quite clearly points out that the mantissa can only be 38 digits long and the  exponent can only be as high as 127. (38+1)+127 = 166. Therefore, reading the documentation for `NSDecimalNumber` and using an online Fibonacci calculator that tells you the digit length could've avoided this. :)

Comment: That's a good point on the maximum length of the mantissa.  He will get incorrect values long before he runs out of digits.  I'll update the answer with that too.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda had that assumption, it is disappointing. I was having better success using Java's Big Number classes. I will have to look at the link, I don't want to just Google the answer, but I never did the math that NSDecimalNumber's maximum size.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that the libraries mentioned in the linked answer give functionality similar to the Big Number classes (although I'm not a Java guy. :) ).

Comment: So far they have not proven easy to work with in the latest version of Objective-C. One isn't compatible with ARC... in short it isn't easy to just download the source and drop it in as posters would lead you believe... I'm pretty disappointed with my coding experience today, a lot of time spent with little to no return.

Comment: If it helps, you can specify that a particular file is non-ARC by using the `-fno-objc-arc` flag as shown in this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6646052/937822 .  Most of the libraries are C libraries and you shouldn't have to do much else to use them.